# Javascript Calculating year diff error in date?

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to understand the date in JavaScript. But I can't get it.

I create a function that takes two dates and returns a value based on the difference of dates.

Here is the whole code:

```
function checkDate(birth_date, download_date) {
    let yearDiff = download_date.getFullYear() - birth_date.getFullYear();
    console.log(yearDiff);
    if (yearDiff > 5) return "Not Eligible";
    if (yearDiff < 5) return "Eligible";
    if (yearDiff == 5) {
        // Eligible only if 5 years or low

        // If diff is Exact 5 Years Check if Bday is on download date ?
        // First Check Month
        let monthDiff = download_date.getMonth() - birth_date.getMonth();
        if (monthDiff >= 1) {
            return "Not Eligible"
        }
        if (monthDiff <= -1) {
            return "Eligible"
        }

        if (monthDiff = 0) {
            // Check Day
            let dateDiff = download_date.getDay() - birth_date.getDay();

            if (dateDiff <= 0) {
                return "Eligible"
            } else {
                return "Not Eligible"
            }
        }
    }
}

let dob_string = "DOB: 14/09/2016";
let dl_string = "Download Date: 03/11/2020";

let dob = new Date(dob_string.substr(dob_string.indexOf("DOB:") + 4, 11).trim());
let dld = new Date(dl_string.substr(dl_string.indexOf("Download") + 14, 11).trim());

console.log(checkDate(dob,dld));
```

The is the date is not getting created it says `Invalid Date`.

I want to check if the DOB difference is 5 more or not.

Comment: it might have not much to do with your problem, but ` if (monthDiff = 0) {` seems not looking correct

Comment: If you are passing `"DOB: 14/09/2016"` to `Date` then that might be where the problem is. `new date("DOB: 14/09/2016")` is definitely not valid.

Comment: @nibble have you checked the whole code ? i don't think you did. I am extracting the date from the string using substring.

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz whoops!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

so i tested it and even the substrings creates invalid dates.
so i wrote you this:

```js
function checkDate(birth_date, download_date) {
    let yearDiff = download_date.getFullYear() - birth_date.getFullYear();
    console.log(yearDiff);
    if (yearDiff > 5) return "Not Eligible";
    if (yearDiff < 5) return "Eligible";
    if (yearDiff == 5) {
        // Eligible only if 5 years or low

        // If diff is Exact 5 Years Check if Bday is on download date ?
        // First Check Month
        let monthDiff = download_date.getMonth() - birth_date.getMonth();
        if (monthDiff >= 1) {
            return "Not Eligible"
        }
        if (monthDiff <= -1) {
            return "Eligible"
        }

        if (monthDiff == 0) {
            // Check Day
            let dateDiff = download_date.getDay() - birth_date.getDay();

            if (dateDiff <= 0) {
                return "Eligible"
            } else {
                return "Not Eligible"
            }
        }
    }
}

let dob_string = "DOB: 14/09/2016";
let dl_string = "Download Date: 03/11/2020";

function filterDate(str) {
    const match = str.match(/(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2}).(\d{4})/);
    let year = match[3];
    let month = match[2];
    let day = match[1];
    if (isNaN(year) || isNaN(month) || isNaN(day)) {
        throw new Error("no valid date");
    }
    // fix strings to numbers;
    year = +year;
    month = +month;
    day = +day;
    // months begins on 0
    month = month - 1;
    return new Date(year, month, day);
}

console.log(checkDate(filterDate(dob_string),filterDate(dl_string)));
```

Comment: What about null handling ? if the string does not includes the desired pattern the program would crash. the isNan would only work if the pattern is matched.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `new Date` constructor [doesn't understand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) `dd/mm/yyyy` format and is implemented differently on different browsers. What you need to do is convert it into valid format.
One way is to split it and pass into the constructor like this:

```
let dob_string = "DOB: 14/09/2016";
let dl_string = "Download Date: 03/11/2020";
let dob = dob_string.substr(dob_string.indexOf("DOB:") + 4, 11).trim();
const splitDOB = dob.split('/')
const validDate = new Date(
  parseInt(splitDOB[2], 10),
  parseInt(splitDOB[1], 10) - 1,
  parseInt(splitDOB[0], 10)
);
```

The `- 1` in the second param is because month is [0-indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date). Then you can process with the logic of your own function.
But I highly recommend using 3rd party lib such as [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) when working with date/time in JS